# JQuery Cross-Domain .load() (self-constructing widget)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a widget for people to use on their websites, however to keep the widget future-proof, i want it to be self constructing using an external javascript.

So the widget code i would ask people to put on their websites would be something like:

```
<div id="my_widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.external-domain.com/mywidget.js"></script>
```

`mywidget.js` would then use jquery's `.load()` to populate the `#my_widget` div with an iframe.

Problem is this doesn't work....

what do i need to do?

*(note i dont want to have the iframe in the code i give to my customers)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what url you are specifying in the `load` function. If this url is not hosted on the same domain that executes the page containing this script won't work due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction. One possible workaround to make cross domain ajax calls is to use [JSON-P](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) if you have control over the server side script which is used in the `load` function.

Here's the idea behind JSON-P:

1. You provide a server side script hosted on Domain A which will return JSONP formatted response. Domain A is your domain for which you have full control.
2. This server side script could be called from Domain B using AJAX.

Let's suppose that `http://domainA.com/myscript?jsoncallback=foo` returns the following response:

```
foo({ result: '<strong>Hello World</strong>' });
```

Now inside `mywidget.js` you could call this script:

```
$.getJSON('http://domainA.com/myscript?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $('#my_widget').html(data.result);
});
```

All that is left is to tell the users include `mywidget.js` script and provide a placeholder with `id="my_widget"` to host the results (you could even generate this placeholder in the success callback).

Remark: When using JSONP you are limited to GET requests only. This means that there's a limit in the size of the request you can send.

Comment: It seems like he's letting people put that `<script>` on their site... so his code is executed on their site... there's no *same origin policy* thing.. it's just executing his code, which is a standard thing that lots of people do.

Comment: Except that in his widget he is using the `.load` method to perform an AJAX request.

Comment: see my response below Luca, i'm pretty sure darin is right here, i think i need some advise for using jsonp

Comment: or just an iframe, like you specified in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have total control of their page since you're executing **your** code on their site.

You can create iframes `document.createElement("iframe")`, inject it anywhere on the page `document.getElementById("my_widget").appendChild(iframe)` and do whatever else you feel like.

One thing to be careful with this is to not clutter their namespaces... avoid any *usual* namespace and make up your own (__my_widget or whatever else is weird). And try to keep the namespaces counts as low as 1, or even none if possible.

Don't use **load**, use an iframe if you're just trying to load html from your site.

Comment: the content is not composed inside the mywidget.js file, the js file uses ajax to load in html from my server to their website

Comment: don't use ajax, use an iframe like you specified.

Comment: You dont need to give the iframe code to your costumer.. you need your JS to dynamically create the iframe for you and change it's `src` attribute to point to your page on your domain...