# Error when loading Plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I created a Plug-in for friends and it works perfectly on my website. But, whenever I post it on another server, it doesn't work. When the page is loaded, it goes through all of the steps of the function `loadBox()` but, it fails to load the PHP page inside of the `<div>`. It just keeps the .gif running. Please help. This is really annoying. Here's what we're posting to get the plug-in:

```
<div id="ferridev_twitter_box" load_type="personal" twitter_name="jpferrierjr" tweet_number="15" tone="dark"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.johnferrier.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.johnferrier.com/plugins/twitter/js/ferridev_twitter_plug-in.js"></script>
```

The `jquery.js` file is just a standard jQuery file. But, the `ferridev_twitter_plug-in.js` is the one that I made. It's contents look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function loadBox()
    {
        $('#ferridev_twitter_box').html("<div style='height:400px; width:300px; padding-top:167px; text-align:center;'><center><span style='position:relative;'><img src='http://www.johnferrier.com/images/loading/loading17.gif' /></span></center></div>");
        var a = $('#ferridev_twitter_box').attr("twitter_name");
        var b = $('#ferridev_twitter_box').attr("tweet_number");
        var c = $('#ferridev_twitter_box').attr("tone");
        var d = window.location;
        var e = $('#ferridev_twitter_box').attr("load_type");
        $('#ferridev_twitter_box').load("http://www.johnferrier.com/plugins/twitter/php/ferridev_twitter_plug-in_parser.php?name="+a+"&limit="+b+"&tone="+c+"&type="+e);
    }
    loadBox();
});
```

Is ther anything that you guys can see wrong with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not impossible, you could use jsonp to set up a universal web service like that, BUT cross domain javascript is difficult due to browser security.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/cross-domain-load

[JQuery Cross-Domain .load() (self-constructing widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889001/jquery-cross-domain-load-self-constructing-widget)

This may work for you:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain policy restriction. You're trying to do an ajax request to another server.

```
$('#ferridev_twitter_box').load("http://www.johnferrier.com/plugins/twitter/php/ferridev_twitter_plug-in_parser.php?name="+a+"&limit="+b+"&tone="+c+"&type="+e);
```

Check out these examples of cross-domain ajax: http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide