# Grabbing contents from another web page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started to learn jQuery. I came across this "Grabbing contents from other webpage".
I was going through the code in one of the sites as how to achieve it, here is the part of it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list').load("http://www.narutoget.com ul", function(responseText){
        $('#otherHtml').text(responseText);
    });
});
```

I'm not able to get contents from the page i.e narutoget.com. 
Can some one help me out as to how to achieve it?
And I would like to know if it's legal to do it.

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: I'm sorry of cause... i edited my comment. What he tried is indeed obvious but not, what went wrong. "I'm not able to get contents" is not a very detailed description of what happens when he tried his code. Is the success handler called or not? Is it just the page which is unavailable? Maybe there is a javascript error because he's may not delivering the page from a web server. You can't just give an answer with this information.

Comment: Well, generally that's true but in this case the information is enough to diagnose the same origin policy problem.

Comment: You cannot load this way as musa suggested its a same origin policy which prevents it.

Comment: @Jai Chris Juhana mussa Well i was hoping if its possible to first use php include funtion.... and then use my above code on my php file will it work then?

Comment: @Chris m not getting anything in return i.e my page is empty....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you aren't maintaining the other site, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) would have prevented it, apart if the other site explicitly allows it by including the good [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and the only solution would be to do it server side, where you can query the server as you want.

If you maintain the other site as well, then you just have to put the good CORS header to let your first site query it.

Here's a good tutorial on enabling cross origin requests for various server side technologies : [enable-cors](http://enable-cors.org/)

Once it's done, you simply have to query the server and analyze the page :

```
$.get("http://www.narutoget.com", function(html) {
    var ul = $('ul', html).val();
    $('#otherHtml').text(ul);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely blocked from cross-site-origin policy.
JSON-P is one way to get around this, [JQuery Cross-Domain .load() (self-constructing widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889001/jquery-cross-domain-load-self-constructing-widget)

Are you getting errors? Look in a web inspector under NET and see what the status code is for that request. If there aren't any errors or cross-domain restrictions, I don't see what the problem is. Are you getting any text at all?

Comment: Well i was hoping if its possible to first use php include funtion.... and then use my above code on my php file will it work then?